# Delphi. WinInet + cisco + NTLM. 12045 and 12057 errors

Tags: delphi, winapi, ssl, ntlm, wininet

Подключаюсь к корпоративной сети через cisco, а дальше доменная ntlm авторизация на корп. https сайт. Так вот прокси прохожу (достаточно в IE один раз вести логин с паролем) и программа ходит на все сайты, кроме корпоративного, на нем валится ошибка 12045 (ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_CA) или 12057. Как подсунуть сертификат из хранилища? Естественно не используя логин с паролем и его название.
Помогите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с таким. Через http пробовал. Вот функция:

```pascal
function WinInetRequest(AUrl, AParam, AMethod, AType_Access: String; APostData: boolean): AnsiString;

  function GetHostName(AUrl: string): string;
  var
    s: string;
  begin // Имя хоста
    if Pos('https://', AUrl) > 0 then
      s:= 'https://'
    else
      if Pos('http://', AUrl) > 0 then
        s:= 'http://'
      else
        s:= EmptyStr;
    if s <> EmptyStr then
      if Pos(s, AUrl) > 0 then
        Delete(AUrl, 1, Length(s));
    if Pos('/', AUrl) > 0 then
      SetLength(AUrl, Pos('/', AUrl) - 1);
    Result:= AUrl;
  end;

  function GetScriptName(AUrl, AHostname: string): string;
  begin // URL после имени хоста
    Result:= EmptyStr;
    Delete(AUrl, 1, Pos(AHostname, AUrl) + Length(AHostname));
    Result:= AUrl;
  end;

  procedure SetFlags(AUrl: string; out Flags_connection, Flags_Request: Cardinal);
  begin // Определяем https или http
    if Pos('https', AUrl) > 0 then
    begin
      Flags_connection:= INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT;
      Flags_Request:= INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
                   or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION;
    end else
      begin
        Flags_connection:= INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
        Flags_Request:= INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE or INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE or INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION;
      end;
  end;

var
  hInet, hCon, hReq: HINTERNET;
  Status, Index, dwErrorCode, StatusSize: DWORD;
  bytes, b, pos: Cardinal;
  hostname, script: string;
  Flags_connection, Flags_Request : Cardinal;
  IsSended: Boolean;

label
  again;
begin
  Result:= EmptyAnsiStr;

  hostname:= GetHostName(AUrl); // имя хоста
  script:= GetScriptName(AUrl, hostname); // скрипт
  // установка доп. параметров
  if not APostData then // если передаем параметры через строку запроса, то
    if AParam <> EmptyStr then // дополняем скрипт
      if script[Length(script)] = '?' then
        script:= script + AParam
      else
        script:= script + '?' + AParam;

  // Type_Access
  if AType_Access = EmptyStr then
    AType_Access:= 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlenDELPHId' + #13#10 +
                'Content-Length:' + IntToStr(length(AParam)) ;

  try
    // Устанавливаем флаги (http или https)
    SetFlags(AUrl, Flags_connection, Flags_Request);
    // Инициализируем WinInet
    hInet:= InternetOpen(PChar(Application.ExeName), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0); //
    if Assigned(hInet) then
    try
      // Открываем сессию (передаем имя сервера hostname в ф-ю InternetConnect под параметром lpszServerName)
      hCon:= InternetConnect(hInet, PChar(hostname), Flags_connection, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
      if Assigned(hCon) then
      try
        // Открываем запрос (передаем остаток URL (скрипт GetScriptName) в ф-ю HttpOpenRequest под параметром lpszObjectName)
        hReq:= HttpOpenRequest(hCon, PChar(UpperCase(AMethod)), PChar(script), HTTP_VERSION, nil, nil, Flags_Request, 1);
        if Assigned(hReq) then
        try // Отправляем запрос
          case APostData of
            False: IsSended:= HttpSendRequest(hReq, nil, 0, nil, 0);
            True: IsSended:= HttpSendRequest(hReq, PChar(AType_Access), Length(AType_Access), PChar(AParam), Length(AParam));
          end;
          if not IsSended then // отработка ошибки сертификата
          begin
                        // Окно авторизации
              {InternetErrorDlg(Application.Handle,
                               hReq,
                               ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_CA,
                               FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FILTER_FOR_ERRORS
                            or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_GENERATE_DATA
                            or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_CHANGE_OPTIONS,
                               hReq);}
              dwErrorCode:= GetLastError;
              if (dwErrorCode = 12045) then
              begin
                ShowMessage('Ошибка сертификата!');
                Status:= INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE
                     or  INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
                     or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION;
                StatusSize:= SizeOf(Status);
                InternetQueryOption(hReq, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @Status, StatusSize);
                Status:= Status or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA;
                InternetSetOption(hReq, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @Status, SizeOf(Status));

                case APostData of
                  False: IsSended:= HttpSendRequest(hReq, nil, 0, nil, 0);
                  True: IsSended:= HTTPSendRequest(hReq, PChar(AType_Access), Length(AType_Access), PChar(AParam), Length(AParam));
                end;
              end;

          end;
          if IsSended then
          begin
            StatusSize:= SizeOf(Status);
            Index:= 0;
            HttpQueryInfo(hReq, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE or HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, @Status, StatusSize, Index);
            if Status <> HTTP_STATUS_OK then
              Result:= AnsiString('Код ответа сервера: ' + IntToStr(Status) + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
            pos:= 1;
            b:= 1;
            while b > 0 do
            begin // Если количество данных 0 - генерируем исключение
              if not InternetQueryDataAvailable(hReq, bytes, 0, 0) then
                Result:= AnsiString('Сервер не вернул данные! (функция InternetQueryDataAvailable)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
              SetLength(Result, Cardinal(Length(Result)) + bytes);
              // Получаем данные с сервера
              InternetReadFile(hReq, @Result[Pos], bytes, b);
              Inc(Pos, b);
            end;
          end else
            Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка ' + IntToStr(GetLastError) + '!');
        finally
          InternetCloseHandle(hReq); // закрываем запрос
        end else
          Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка формирования запроса (функция HttpOpenRequest)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
      finally
        InternetCloseHandle(hCon); // закрываем сессию
      end else
        Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка открытия сессии (функция InternetConnect)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hInet); // закрываем соединение
    end else
      Result:= AnsiString('Отсутствует подключение к сети (функция InternetOpen)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  except
    On E: Exception do
      Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка! ' + E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Кстати, если перед sendRequest задать опции

```
dwFlags:= dwFlags
               or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA
               or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
               or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
               or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION;
             // Set new flags
             if not(InternetSetOption(httpRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @dwFlags, dwSize)) then
```

то выдается ошибка авторизации 401. В сниффере то же самое, но браузер идет дальше, а программа больше не отрабатывает редиректы. Может в этом дело?

**Дополнение**

Проблему с сертификатом решил, использую ключи:
`SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA 
or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID 
or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID or 
SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION`

Когда захожу в первый раз через IE - просит ввести пароль, при отказе ввода выводит 401, то же самое, что и в программе на текущий момент.
Если введу пароль - IE дальше использует куки и ходит на сайт без проблем пока не почищу их.
Лог программы:

```
CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: C:\Dev\Testing.exe
Host: site.ru:443
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 08:58:58.805
Connection: close
EndTime: 08:59:16.562
ClientToServerBytes: 1946
ServerToClientBytes: 6185

------------------------------------------------------------------

GET http://site.ru/cert/root.crt HTTP/1.1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Microsoft-CryptoAPI/10.0
Host: site.ru


HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 05:59:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Timestamp: 08:59:20.404

------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Лог IE:

```
CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:42:39.636
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:42:54.716
ClientToServerBytes: 205
ServerToClientBytes: 3183



------------------------------------------------------------------

GET http://site.ru/cert/root.crt HTTP/1.1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Microsoft-CryptoAPI/10.0
Host: site.ru


HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 06:43:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Timestamp: 09:43:00.722



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:42:54.747
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:42:54.785
ClientToServerBytes: 205
ServerToClientBytes: 3183



------------------------------------------------------------------ сайт не защищен (Error Code: DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA, нажимаю "перейти на страницу (не рекомендуется))

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:44:14.163
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:44:29.231
ClientToServerBytes: 205
ServerToClientBytes: 3183



------------------------------------------------------------------

GET http://site.ru/cert/root.crt HTTP/1.1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Microsoft-CryptoAPI/10.0
Host: site.ru


HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 06:44:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Timestamp: 09:44:35.225



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:44:29.294
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:44:29.362
ClientToServerBytes: 205
ServerToClientBytes: 3183



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:44:29.384
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:20.611
ClientToServerBytes: 36558
ServerToClientBytes: 168803



------------------------------------------------------------------ - ввожу пароль

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:10.675
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:20.620
ClientToServerBytes: 24661
ServerToClientBytes: 284264



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:10.674
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:20.628
ClientToServerBytes: 21760
ServerToClientBytes: 117787



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:10.674
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:12.743
ClientToServerBytes: 10519
ServerToClientBytes: 17470



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:10.674
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:14.875
ClientToServerBytes: 12684
ServerToClientBytes: 57032



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:10.673
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:27.157
ClientToServerBytes: 19947
ServerToClientBytes: 462607



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:10.673
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:12.729
ClientToServerBytes: 10348
ServerToClientBytes: 26830



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:10.668
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:29.979
ClientToServerBytes: 27178
ServerToClientBytes: 645488



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:10.673
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:14.866
ClientToServerBytes: 23141
ServerToClientBytes: 63723



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:10.673
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:29.563
ClientToServerBytes: 17702
ServerToClientBytes: 1107864



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:10.675
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:13.329
ClientToServerBytes: 5053
ServerToClientBytes: 43534



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:10.675
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:14.880
ClientToServerBytes: 19979
ServerToClientBytes: 91116



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:12.974
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:21.599
ClientToServerBytes: 15295
ServerToClientBytes: 198021



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:12.987
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:20.589
ClientToServerBytes: 21600
ServerToClientBytes: 221667



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT piwik.mts.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: piwik.mts.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:13.368
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:28.443
ClientToServerBytes: 201
ServerToClientBytes: 2048



------------------------------------------------------------------

GET http://site.ru/cert/win.crt HTTP/1.1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Microsoft-CryptoAPI/10.0
Host: site.ru


HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2020 06:45:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Timestamp: 09:45:34.440



------------------------------------------------------------------

CONNECT site.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: site.ru
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Basic ****************


HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 09:45:16.694
Connection: close
EndTime: 09:45:21.579
ClientToServerBytes: 20336
ServerToClientBytes: 179279
```

Приложение не отправляет заголовки с логином и паролем сайту... вероятно, что из-за этого у меня и не выходит подключиться. Добавление

```
InternetSetOption(httpConnect,INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME,PChar('login'),SizeOf('login'));
InternetSetOption(httpConnect,INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD,PChar('Pass'),SizeOf('Pass'));
```

перед очередным sendrequest не помогает.
Пробовал указывать как httpConnect, так и httpRequest

Comment: Т.е. сертификат само-подписанный? У вас есть корпоративный корневой сертификат, которым подписывается сертификат для сайта?

Comment: Да, есть. В логах фидлера видел 2 сертификата, полагаю, что один от сайта, второй корневой

Comment: Если там действительно есть корневой сертификат, то импортируется он следующим образом: [Установка корневого сертификата в браузере Google Chrome](https://wiki.webmoney.ru/projects/webmoney/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5_Google_Chrome)

Comment: zed,  спасибо! Но у меня же через IE доступ есть, сертификат не устанавливаю, только в сообщении браузера "Ваше подключение не защищено" нажимаю Дополнительно - продолжить и разово ввожу логин с паролем

Comment: У вас тут 2 проблемы: первая - с сертификатом, вторая - с авторизацией. Проблему с сертификатом можно решить либо установкой корневого сертификата, либо использованием флагов `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_XXX`. После решения проблемы с сертификатом, смотрите снифером чем отличаются запросы/ответы вашего кода от браузера. Возможно не хватает ещё каких-то флагов/настроек/прав доступа, а возможно ещё что-то. Соответственно, желательно приложить в вопрос и логи снифера.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос логами сниффера

Comment: Вы делаете запрос к site.ru? Из лога я вижу только, что проблема на стороне сервера ([код ответа 502](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502)). И ответ одинаковый что для браузера, что для вашей программы.

Comment: Я не все логи прикрепил, там куча редиректов. Самое главное, что 1-е 2 запроса одинаковы и в программе, и в браузере, но браузер идет дальше...

Comment: Последний код ответа браузеру - 200, а подключение, конечно, не к site.ru, по понятным причинам не раскрываю имя хоста)

Comment: Пробовал делать и так - бесполезно

`dwSize:= SizeOf(dwFlags);
Index:= 0;
HttpQueryInfo(httpRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE or HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, @dwFlags, dwSize, Index);            
if dwFlags = 401 then
begin              
  ShowMessage('Не авторизован!');
  s:= PChar('login');
  dwSize:= SizeOf(s);
  InternetSetOption(httpConnect,INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME,@s,dwSize);
  s:= PChar('pass');
  dwSize:= SizeOf(s);
  InternetSetOption(httpConnect,INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD,@s,dwSize);
end;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добился подключения только через

```
InternetErrorDlg(Application.Handle, httpRequest,
ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED,
FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FILTER_FOR_ERRORS
or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_GENERATE_DATA
or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_CHANGE_OPTIONS,
PPointer(nil)^ )
```

Заголовки все равно различаются, кстати, я привел неправильные заголовки в вопросе, т.к. они без https.

Ниже код модуля с готовым объектом для использования под cisco vpn, например, если вы хотите подключаться из дома к корпоративному порталу и прочему. Не претендую на чистоту кода, много лишнего и местами криво, но функции выполняет. Замечу, что логин нужно указывать как domain\login.

```
{
Если логин с паролем не указывать (в конструкторе или после создания), то , при
необходимости будет выскакивать окно с запросом
}

unit UnitWinInet;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, WinInet, Winapi.Windows;

type

  TWinInet = class
    private
      FHWND: THandle; // Хэндл вызывающего приложения
      FClientName, // Имя клиента
      FParam, // параметры запроса (которые после ?)
      FMethod, // GET, POST и др.
      FType_Access, // mime type и проч, если установлен в '', то используется по умолчанию
      FLogin, // логин
      FPass: string; // пароль
      FPostData: boolean; //True - передача параметров запроса через post data, False - через строку запроса
      procedure SetMethod(AMethod: string);
    public
      property HWND: THandle read FHWND write FHWND;
      property ClientName: string read FClientName write FClientName;
      property Param: string read FParam write FParam;
      property Method: string read FMethod write SetMethod;
      property Type_Access: string read FType_Access write FType_Access;
      property Login: string read FLogin write FLogin;
      property Pass: string read FPass write FPass;
      property PostData: boolean read FPostData write FPostData;
      function GetHTTP(AURL: string): AnsiString;
      constructor Create(AHWND: THandle);
  end;

implementation


constructor TWinInet.Create(AHWND: THandle);
begin
  FHWND:= AHWND;
  FClientName:= 'WinInet';
  FMethod:= 'GET';
  FType_Access:= 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlenDELPHId' + #13#10 +
                   'Content-Length:' + IntToStr(length(FParam));
  FPostData:= False;
end;

procedure TWinInet.SetMethod(AMethod: string);
begin
  FMethod:= UpperCase(AMethod);
end;

function TWinInet.GetHTTP(AURL: string): AnsiString;

  function GetHostName(AUrl: string): string;
  var
    s: string;
  begin // Имя хоста
    if Pos('https://', AUrl) > 0 then
      s:= 'https://'
    else
      if Pos('http://', AUrl) > 0 then
        s:= 'http://'
      else
        s:= EmptyStr;
    if s <> EmptyStr then
      if Pos(s, AUrl) > 0 then
        Delete(AUrl, 1, Length(s));
    if Pos('/', AUrl) > 0 then
      SetLength(AUrl, Pos('/', AUrl) - 1);
    Result:= AUrl;
  end;

  function GetScriptName(AUrl, AHostname: string): string;
  begin // URL после имени хоста
    Result:= EmptyStr;
    Delete(AUrl, 1, Pos(AHostname, AUrl) + Length(AHostname));
    Result:= AUrl;
  end;

  procedure SetFlags(AUrl: string; out Flags_connection, Flags_Request: Cardinal);
  begin // Определяем https или http
    if Pos('https', AUrl) > 0 then
    begin
      Flags_connection:= INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT;
      Flags_Request:= INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
                   or INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION
    end else
      begin
        Flags_connection:= INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
        Flags_Request:= INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE
                     or INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION;
      end;
  end;

  function GetResponseHeader(const hRequest: Pointer): string;
  var
    dwSize, Index: DWORD;
    szBuff: array [0..1024] of Char;
  begin // Возвращает заголовок ответа сервера в виде строк с CR/LF
    Index:= 0;
    dwSize:= SizeOf(szBuff);
    HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, @szBuff, dwSize, Index);
    Result:= PChar(@szBuff);
  end;

  function GetStatus(const hRequest: Pointer): DWORD;
  var
    dwSize, dwStatus, Index: DWORD;
  begin // Возвращает заголовок ответа сервера в виде строк с CR/LF
    // Возвращает код статуса HTTP из заголовка ответа
    Index:= 0;
    dwSize:= SizeOf(dwStatus);
    HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE or HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, @dwStatus, dwSize, Index);
    Result:= dwStatus;
  end;

  function AddSecurityFlags(httpReq: Pointer): Boolean;
  var
    dwSize, dwFlags: DWORD;
  begin
    Result:= False;
    dwSize:= SizeOf(dwFlags);     // Get the current security flags
    if (InternetQueryOption(httpReq, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @dwFlags, dwSize)) then
    begin // Add desired flags
       dwFlags:= dwFlags
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
         or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION;
       Result:= (InternetSetOption(httpReq,
              INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,
              @dwFlags,
              dwSize));
    end
  end;

  function SendRequest(httpRequest: Pointer; AType_Access, AParam: string): boolean;
  begin
    case FPostData of
      False: Result:= HttpSendRequest(httpRequest, nil, 0, nil, 0);
      True: Result:= HttpSendRequest(httpRequest, PChar(AType_Access), Length(AType_Access), PChar(AParam), Length(AParam));
    end;
  end;

var
  httpSession, httpConnect, httpRequest: HINTERNET;
  bytes, b, pos: Cardinal;
  hostname, script: string;
  Flags_connection, Flags_Request: Cardinal;
  DlgError: DWORD;
begin
  Result:= EmptyAnsiStr;
  hostname:= GetHostName(AURL); // имя хоста
  script:= GetScriptName(AURL, hostname); // скрипт
  // установка доп. параметров
  if not FPostData then // если передаем параметры через строку запроса, то
    if FParam <> EmptyStr then // дополняем скрипт
      if script[Length(script)] = '?' then
        script:= script + FParam
      else
        script:= script + '?' + FParam;
  try
    SetFlags(AURL, Flags_connection, Flags_Request); // Устанавливаем флаги (http или https)
    // Открываем сессию (инициализируем WinInet)
    httpSession:= InternetOpen(PChar(FClientName), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
    if Assigned(httpSession) then // Проверяем хэндл
    try // Открываем соединение
      httpConnect:= InternetConnect(httpSession, PChar(hostname), Flags_connection, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
      if Assigned(httpConnect) then // Проверяем хэндл
      try // Открываем запрос (передаем остаток URL (скрипт GetScriptName) в ф-ю HttpOpenRequest под параметром lpszObjectName)
        httpRequest:= HttpOpenRequest(httpConnect, PChar(FMethod), PChar(script), HTTP_VERSION, nil, nil, Flags_Request, 0);
        if Assigned(httpRequest) then
        try
          AddSecurityFlags(httpRequest);
          SendRequest(httpRequest, FType_Access, FParam); // Отправляем запрос
          if GetStatus(httpRequest) = HTTP_STATUS_DENIED then
          begin // Если необходима авторизация
            if FLogin <> EmptyStr then
            begin
              InternetSetOption(httpRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME, PChar(FLogin), SizeOf(FLogin));
              InternetSetOption(httpRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD, PChar(FPass), SizeOf(FPass));
            end
              else
              begin
                DlgError:= InternetErrorDlg(FHWND, httpRequest,
                   ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED,
                   FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FILTER_FOR_ERRORS
                or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_GENERATE_DATA
                   //or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_SERIALIZE_DIALOGS
                or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_CHANGE_OPTIONS,
                   PPointer(nil)^ );
                if DlgError = 0 then
                begin
                  Result:= AnsiString('Доступ запрещен! Ввод учетных данных отменен.'
                   + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
                  Exit;
                end;
              end;
            SendRequest(httpRequest, FType_Access, FParam);
          end;
          if GetStatus(httpRequest) = HTTP_STATUS_OK then
          begin
            pos:= 1;
            b:= 1;
            while b > 0 do
            begin // Если количество данных 0 - генерируем исключение
              if not InternetQueryDataAvailable(httpRequest, bytes, 0, 0) then
                Result:= AnsiString('Сервер не вернул данные! (функция InternetQueryDataAvailable)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
              SetLength(Result, Cardinal(Length(Result)) + bytes);
              // Получаем данные с сервера
              InternetReadFile(httpRequest, @Result[Pos], bytes, b);
              Inc(Pos, b);
            end;
            Result:= Result + AnsiString(sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
          end else
            Result:= AnsiString('ОШИБКА ' + IntToStr(GetStatus(httpRequest)) + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
        finally
          InternetCloseHandle(httpRequest); // закрываем запрос
        end else
          Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка формирования запроса (функция HttpOpenRequest)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
      finally
        InternetCloseHandle(httpConnect); // закрываем соединение
      end else
        Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка открытия сессии (функция InternetConnect)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(httpSession); // закрываем сессию
    end else
      Result:= AnsiString('Отсутствует подключение к сети (функция InternetOpen)' + sLineBreak + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  except
    On E: Exception do
      Result:= AnsiString('Ошибка! ' + E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Использование:

```
uses
  ..., UnitWinInet;
...
  Client:= TWinInet.Create(FrmTesting.Handle);
  with Client do
  try
    if FrmTesting.CheckBox1.Checked then
    begin
      Login:= 'Domen\login';
      Pass:= 'Password';
    end;
    FHTTPResult:= GetHTTP(FrmTesting.Edt1.Text);    
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Client);
  end;
```

Comment: Ошибка `ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED` говорит, что сервер запрашивает авторизацию через сертификат клиента. И раз у вас получается работать с сервером авторизуясь по паролю, значит авторизация через сертификат является опциональной. И в этом случае, серверу можно заранее сказать, что сертификата нет: [Optional Client SSL Certificates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/ssl-in-winhttp#optional-client-ssl-certificates)

Comment: Или можно попробовать вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10000752